# I2C Level translator 5 V to 1.8 V using MOSFET, output look weird

Tags: mosfet, i2c, interface, logic-level, level-translation

I am designing an I2C level translator using MOSFET. I am using BSS138 [DATA SHEET](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BSS138.pdf). My clock can go up to 1 MHz. The output is not coming properly for fast mode plus (CLK = 1 MHz, RISE TIME = FALL TIME = 120 ns). The 1.8 V output is peaking to 2.1 V and slowly settles to 1.8 V.Please find the attached circuit diagram and waveforms. Is it a pull-up resistor issue?

May I know what is wrong with my circuit?

[image: CIRCUIT DIAGRAM]

[image: WAVEFORMS]

[image: I2C SPEC]

Comment: i2c doesn't work that way. i2c output switches between High Z and low.

Comment: I took the circuit from this app note https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf

Comment: The circuit is ok, but your simulation not. I2C output is open drain output. In your simulation, your output (SDA5V) switches between 0 and 5V. During switching, there is a current flow between 5V (V4 and V3) and 1.8V (V1) through MOSFET drain-gate capacitance, which is limited only by Voltage source internal resistance.

Comment: My input is 5V side and output is 1.8V side.To solve the issue you mentioned,may I know what I need to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I2C output is an open drain output. It means it can not provide 5V at output. It can only switch between 0 (low) and High-Z  (high - in this case pullup resistor provides 5V at the line, and not i2c Output).

Your simulation should look like:

[image]

LT Spice uses some parameters when you don't give it right model. As you see it looks good.

But as you can see at Page 3 of AppNote (Chapter 2), this solution is not good for high speed mode.

The bidirectional level shifter can be used for both Standard-mode (up to100 kbit/s) or in Fast-mode (up to 400 kbit/s) I2C-bus systems. It is not intended for Hs-mode systems, which may have a bridge with a level shifting possibility.

If you try with BSS123 FET in your simulation you don't get perfect result. FET can't turn off fast, because of gate-drain and gate-source capacitance.

You could maybe try with other FETS and different values of pullup resistors.

[image]